# Spring jdbc template query returns empty results with multiple arguments

Tags: sql, oracle11g, jdbctemplate, empty-list

Hi i have the following code.

```
public static final MY_QUERY = "Select distinct A.col1, A.col2 from tableA, tableB where A.col1 = ? and A.col2 = ? and b.id = A.id";
```

in my code i basically do this...

```
public List<MyClass> getData(final String input1, final String input2) {
    return this.jdbcTemplate.query(MyQuery, 
                    new Object[] { input1, input2}, 
                    new int[] {Types.VARCHAR, Types.CHAR}, new MyMapper());
}
```

When i run the results .. it returns empty list.

Now if i do this.

```
public static final MY_QUERY_2 = new StringBuilder(96)
.append("Select distinct A.col1, B.col2 from tableA, tableB where A.col1 =").append(input1)
.append(" and A.col2 = ").append(input2).append(" and b.id = A.id").toString();
```

and inside my DAO class

```
public List<MyClass> getData() {
    return this.jdbcTemplate.query(MY_QUERY_2, new MyMapper());
}
```

I get three results.

What is wrong with the first implementation.

Note:If i use only one argument than it works, but if i use 2, than it doesn't.

Comment: What are the datatypes of col1 and col2 in the database? VARCHAR and CHAR?. Also, prefer the first method than the second as the latter is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Yes they are VARCHAR and CHAR. I can't get the first method to work.. as it somehow gives me empty results.

Comment: Could you please run this query in the database and post the results? `select * from v$sql where sql_text like '%Select distinct A.col1%'`

Comment: table or view does not exists.. anyways .. i updated the query.. the columns are both in A. However the results still returns nothing. If I take away int types.. it is still the same.

Comment: That query is to find how these queries are ultimately seen by the SQL engine. I was trying to backtrack the cause of the problem this way. Looks like your current user does NOT have access to the v$sql view. If you have access to SYSDBA account or even a friendly DBA, you can get the above query executed/for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

if i use

```
A.Col2 = 'Input2'
```

than trim is being called.

I solved it by using

```
trim(A.Col2) = ?
```

to get rid of whitespace.